# How do you access a serial port in Python for mobiles?

Tags: python, mobile, usb, serial-port, pys60

The serial port must be over USB cable, from the phone to a computer.

In Java, I got it working by using the following code:

```
CommConnection comm = (CommConnection)Connector.open("comm:USB1");

// Now use comm to read and write data
```

How can I do this in Python for mobiles, specifically PyS60?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this from [here](https://sites.google.com/site/jtoivola/pythonforsymbian%3apys60usb):

```
    import pys60usb
    usb = pys60usb.USBConnection()

    # Connect to port 1. Works with most S60 3rd devices.
    usb.connect( port = 1, mode = pys60usb.ECommExclusive )
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll see what I can do with this.